# Segmentation fault with multiple process

Tags: c, unix, multiprocessing, pipe

Hello guys i have this code that is supposed to implement pipes (|) just like the terminal for example: ls | sort | grep main.
this is the part of code where i handle the pipes:

```
    int pp[numPipes*2];
    for(i = 0; i < numPipes; i++){
        if(pipe(pp + i*2) < 0){ perror("pipe failed"); exit(-1); }
    }

    char **hold[numPipes+1];

    int j = 0;
    hold[j++] = args;

    for(i = 0; i < nargs; i++){
        if(!strcmp(args[i], "|")){
            hold[j++] = args+i+1;

            args[i] = NULL;

        }       
    }
    hold[j] = NULL;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    while(hold[i][0]){

      pid = fork();

      if(pid == 0) { //child process 

            if(i != 0){
            dup2(pp[(i-1)*2], 0);
        }

        if(i != numPipes){
            dup2(pp[i*2+1], 1);
        }
        int c;
        for( c = 0; c < 2 * numPipes; c++ ){
                close( pp[c] );
        }

        execvp(hold[i][0], hold[i]);
        //return only when exec fails 
        perror("exec failed");
        exit(-1);

      } else if(pid > 0) {//parent process 


        if(!async){

            //waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);

        }else printf("this is an async call\n");

      } else { //error occurred 
        perror("fork failed");
        exit(1);
      }
    i++;

    }

    int c;
    for( c = 0; c < 2 * numPipes; c++ ){
        close( pp[c] );
    }
    for(i = 0; i < numPipes+1; i++){
        wait(&status);
    }
```

this code works and execute the command correctly however its giving me a segmentation fault every time i run it and kills the parent process which is supposed not to happen. Does anyone see where this segmentation fault is happening? i cant find it.

Comment: The code works... however its giving me a segmentation fault every time i run it?

Comment: yes what i meant is that it prints the result of the command in the terminal but it also prints segmentation fault @KonradLindenbach

Comment: It would be considerably more compelling to even *glare* at this if you provided it nicely wrapped up in a **compilable** stand-alone program that exhibited the same problem. As it is you're the only one on earth that has it actually "working" (term used rather loosely).

Comment: Yes, please provide the smallest compilable version of the code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: alright @Arkku i think the problem its inside the while loop, but its really hard to debug with multi-process running

Comment: i printf() outside the while and it never print so it should mean the problem its inside the while loop in one of the parents process being created because the children are being executed fine @WhozCraig

Comment: Maybe you should ignore SIGCHLD ?

Comment: how do i do that @wildplasser

Comment: man 2 signal, or better: man 2 sigaction.